# Serilog not logging in .Net WebService ASMX WebMethod

Tags: asp.net, asmx, serilog, webmethod

I have a .Net Web Application which I am successfully logging to file using Serilog and the File Sink. The main application is setting up the logger in the global.asax application start.

The web application assesses web services (also written by me) and I want to log from within the web-service (asmx) but I can't get it to write anything. I have tried multiple ways including setting up the LoggerConfiguration directly before calling the Log functions but with no luck. I have also enabled SelfLog and nothing is output.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated - I've been googling this all day.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get Serilog working in an ASMX web-service I had to declare a private static  logger at the top of the service:

```
private static Serilog.Core.Logger myLog = new LoggerConfiguration().MinimumLevel.Debug().WriteTo.File(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/logs/QuoteEngine.txt"), rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day).CreateLogger();
```

I then call:

```
myLog.Error("Your string") or myLog.Debug("Your string") etc
```

I hope this helps someone having same issues finding the answer.